# Optimize way of moving a view in Android?

Tags: android, performance

I have my code below, which is used to move my view

```
private void movingViewUpDown(int topMargin) {
    final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
            (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) myView.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.topMargin = topMargin;
    myView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
```

It works well, but every movement seems to allocate some memory, and eventually stack up and need GC to clear the memory. So things do get slow down over time.

I wonder if there's a more efficient way of moving my view around, without having the memory problem that slow things up.

Comment: is `myView` some your custom `View`?

Comment: Not a custom view. It's a layout with cardview etc.

Comment: i tried to call setTranslationY multiple times (in ValueAnimator) but didnt see any extra GC activity

Comment: You won't see GC activity until the memory fully used up. But you could trace the memory usage increase when ever the translate is called, using the Android Studio memory monitor.

Comment: ok then i called `setTranslationY` 10k times, waited 3 minutes or so and the memory increased about 150kB, but later on (with no `setTranslationY`) after couple of minutes the memory increased another 200kB so i wouldnt blame `setTranslationY` for that

Comment: I think your App seems to have other memory allocation happening, which add noise to the tabulation. What I tried is, while letting the App idle, no memory increase. But when calling `setTranslationY`, does see about 3-4 k memory increases, compare to none. The below approach `offsetTopAndBottom` doesn't have memory increase as `setTranslationY`

Comment: keep in mind that `offsetTopAndBottom` is a poor man tool: every parent re-layout completely invalidates any changes made by that method, you can add simple `EditText` and test it by pressing enter once or more times

Comment: Good advice indeed @pskink. Ues, that's what I faced. Perhaps the solution is not ideal once invalidates happens. Wonder why Android provide such API, and what's its real use?

Comment: i have no idea really

Answer (score 1):

View.setLayoutParams() really behaves low performance as requestLayout will be triggered. In fact, you should alway avoid calling this for moving a View.

You can try `View.offsetTopAndBottom(int offset)` to move vertically or
`View.offsetLeftAndRight(int offset)` horizontally, which will achieve good performance.

Comment: Thanks Huangjh, this does solve the memory issue. So I give a upvote to your answer. But the behavior seems not identical to setLayout. What I meant was, I'm having my view on top of the recyclerview, the moved view got place back to original position (which eliminate my moving action done). Wonder if you know why?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know about it.

Answer (score 0):

try using animate method from View class
e.g.:

```
yourView.animate()
    .translationY(translationY)
    .setDuration(animationDuration)
    .start();
```

Comment: Thanks. But not really helping... still consume similar size of memory :(